# Removing unknown chars in xml and process using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml which has a char unknown symbols like '�'etc i need to remove it while processing  XSLT

I am getting this error `Character reference "&#56256" is an invalid XML character.`

Comment: It's not valid xml, so you can't use xslt on it. Have to clean it up first or make whatever created it, produce vakid xml.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a link to the file?

Comment: You may be able to read the file as a text file, using the XSLT 2.0 `unparsed-text()` function, then remove the unwanted characters, then output the result. From here on you can process the result of the first transformation -- as an XML document and transform it with an XSLT transformation.